# Optimize hover overlay animation

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, clip-path

I created a specific hover effect only with HTML and CSS.

```css
.cont {
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
}
.pre {
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 100%);
    transition: height 0.5s 0.5s;
}

.pre ~ .pre {
    background: red;
    bottom: auto;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%);
}

.cont:hover .pre {
    height: 100%;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}


.post {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, clip-path 0.5s;
    background: green;
    opacity: 0;
}

.post ~ .post {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 50%, 0 100%);
}

.cont:hover .post {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, clip-path 0.5s 0.5s;
}

.post ~ .post:hover {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 80%, 0 100%);
}

.post:hover ~ .post {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 10% 20%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="pre">
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:80px;right:80px;">
      some complex html content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pre">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:80px;">
      different complex html content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:80px;right:80px;">
      some complex html content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:80px;">
      different complex html content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The snippet shows the fully working hover effect, but the implementation is pretty awkward.
It uses two divs (class="pre") for creating the "overlay" effect and two separate divs (class="post"), which are only set to `opacity: 1` after the "overlay" effect has completed, for creating the "toggle" effect. Also the "toggle" effect is delayed, thus feels kind of sluggish.

I am looking for an implementation (only HTML+CSS) that only uses two `div`s (+container div) to create the same effects and/or an implementation that removes the "toggle"-delay.
I've already tried using `animation` to do the "overlay" effect but to no avail.

Any ideas on how a two-`div` (no pseudo elements) implementation of this effect could be accomplished?

Comment: Perhaps use pseudo elements on pre and post.

Comment: with using pseudo elements there still would be two "objects" for the "overlay" and two different "objects" for the "toggle", would it? (i understand pseudo elements as individual "objects") But I'm looking for a solution that only uses two "objects" that create the full effect.

Comment: I don’t really understand the comment. A pseudo element is just CSS, not an addition to the DOM. There would be just one pre and one post elements in the HTML inside .cont.

Comment: I've edited the snippet to make more clear, why I can't use pseudo elements. pseudo elements can't contain HMTL but only text.